# how can handle jwplayer player actions with custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I downloaded 'JW-Player-5.2-Pro' and my files are shown in the picture. theres no 'jwplayer.js' file there so can't use javascript api. 'video.flv' is embeded on 'readme.html' as:

```
<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="400" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
    <embed
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"![enter image description here][1]
        id="player2"
        name="player2"
        src="player.swf" 
        width="400" 
        height="315"
        allowscriptaccess="always" 
        allowfullscreen="true"
        flashvars="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" 
    />
</object>
```

but I want to handle the player actions by custom buttons. how can I do that ?

-thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can upgrade to jw player 6 and use the function `jwplayer().load([{file:"/assets/myVideo.mp4"}]);` according to [the jwplayer website](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)

so if your html is something like

```
<button id="play">play </button>
```

then you can use some javascript like this (illustrating using jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play").click(function(){
        jwplayer().load([{file:"/assets/myVideo.mp4"}]);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript API referenced is for JW Player version 6, not 5.2. You need to upgrade if you want to use that API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on JW5 and don't want to use the JS API, you can always make a custom Flash plugin for custom buttons.