# 'jwplayer player 5.2 pro' player actions

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I downloaded 'JW-Player-5.2-Pro' and my files are shown in the picture. theres no 'jwplayer.js' file there so can't use javascript api. 'video.flv' is embeded on 'readme.html' as:

```
<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="400" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
    <embed
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        id="player2"
        name="player2"
        src="player.swf" 
        width="400" 
        height="315"
        allowscriptaccess="always" 
        allowfullscreen="true"
        flashvars="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" 
    />
</object>
```

but I want to handle the player actions(http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference) by custom buttons. how can I do that ?

-thanks.[image]

Comment: If you post your question a second time, [please remove the first one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19194796/893780).

Comment: no, its my first time.

Answer (score 1):

That reference you're point at is for JW Player 6, not 5.2. I just downloaded JW Player 6 and there's a file called `jwplayer.js` and `jwplayer.html5.js` there. So you need to upgrade.

Comment: I see, ok let me try latest version.

Comment: theres a message 'Error loading player: Offline playback not supported'.why is that? my code is  <script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
   flashplayer: "jwplayer.flash.swf",
   file: "video.flv",
   image: "preview.jpg"
  });
 </script>

Comment: JW Player only works when served from a web server. You can't just open a local HTML file and use it. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28840/troubleshooting-your-setup/

Comment: so do you know any jw player version which can work both online and offline and also can use javascript for player actions ? cause its easier to check the codes offline while trying to create custom buttons for player actions. (5.2 pro version doesn't have jwplayer.js file.)

Comment: There isn't one to my knowledge. It's not hard to set up a local web server to test on though. Should take all of 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to trigger player actions by custom buttons than
you should do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick='jwplayer().play()'>Start playback</li>
    <li onclick='alert(jwplayer().getVolume())'>Get audio volume</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to handle the events you should go with :

```
jwplayer().onPlay(function(){
      //your code goes here
})
```

**Works with jwpalyer 6.0**

Answer (score 0):

You should really upgrade to JW6 because then you can make use of the JavaScript API. Staying on JW5 and using the object method of embed is pretty old. The only way of adding buttons in this case is via a custom Flash plugin for JW5.